# Error in installing EntityframeworkwithheirarchyId6.0.2

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Hi I have a problem in installing entityframeworkwithheirarchyId how can I fix it. I installed and reinstalled few time but its not work.

```
       Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly                                   `EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility, 
       Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6847f3395fc61b47' or one of its           dependencies. Strong name validation fai
led. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)"
At D:\ 2012\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId.6.0.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:669 char:62
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom <<<< ((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.Ut
ility.dll))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\ 2012\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId.6.0.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:670 char:50
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CreateInstance:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.PowerShell
, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6847f3395fc61b47' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature co
uld not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the corr
ect private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)"
At D:\ 2012\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId.6.0.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:698 char:31
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility, 
Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6847f3395fc61b47' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation fai
led. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)"
At D:\ 2012\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId.6.0.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:669 char:62
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom <<<< ((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.Ut
ility.dll))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\ 2012\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId.6.0.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:670 char:50
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CreateInstance:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.PowerShell
, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6847f3395fc61b47' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature co
uld not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the corr
ect private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)"
At D:\ 2012\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId.6.0.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:698 char:31
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

what should I do for fixing this problem? I want to have a heirarchical data so problem in configuring this please help me.

Comment: The exception message says exactly what's wrong - strong name verification failed. Where did you take the EF package from? It does not seem to be signed: `Strong name signature co
uld not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the corr
ect private key.`

Comment: Directly dowloaded from Nugget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Package shows its unsigned so try to use another package but its unsatble version.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId/6.1.0-pre1